# Calling database many times for validating every id on database

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I'm developing an API on .Net Core 6 and i'm having a little confusing about all the requests im doing to the database.

For example i have a Company class and Employee Class

```
public class Company
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  public List<Employees> employees { get; set; }
  public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{ 
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public Company Company { get; set; }
  public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
  public User user { get; set; } // This is the IdentityUser
}
```

I have this JSON object i send to api to add an employe

```
{
    "name": "First Last",
    "userId": "1E715D09-D1A4-4853-960B-08D9DED34E35",
    "isAdmin": false
}
```

A user can add a company and immediately is inserted as an employee (Admin employee) because he created that Company. Another thing is that, to be able to add another employee, the Employee (User logged in) needs to be an admin on that company.

I have this endpoint for adding employees: api/company/{companyId}/employees -> POST
and this is the logic i have to add the employee

```
// Verifies that the company sent is a valid one
var company = await _repository.Company.GetCompany(companyId, trackChanges);
    if (company == null)
          throw new NotFoundException("Company could not be found");

// Verifies that the user (getting the userId from the JWT) logged in is an employee in that company so he can add a new employee
var userEmployee = await _repository.Employee.GetEmployeeByUserId(userId, companyId, trackChanges);
        if (userEmployee == null)
            throw new NotFoundException("Employee was not found");

// Validates the user object fetched that he's an admin
if (userEmployee.IsAdmin)
    {
        // Validates that the sent user Id in the DTO is valid to add
        var userToAdd = GetUserById(employeeCreationDto.userId, trackChanges);
        if (userToAdd == null)
            throw new NotFoundException("User trying to be added as emmployee is not found");

        // Verify that the userId from the DTO doesn't exists in the DB already
        var userToAddAsEmployee = await _repository.Employee.GetEmployeeByUserId(employeeCreationDto.userId, companyId, trackChanges);
        if (userToAddAsEmployee != null)
            throw new ConflictException("User is already an employee in this company");

        //Proceed to add employee logic
     }
```

Now my question is, should i do all of this Database calls to validate every single step or should i try to add and if a foreign key error returns from the db just handle that error as response

I just think i am doing to many calls and almost all of my endpoints have lot's of validations calling the db. Is it okay all of those calls?

Comment: too many? how many? affecting performance? consider caching.

Comment: @LeiYang i just think that the GetCompany(), GetEmployeesByUserId(), GetUserById() and the last one are alot of calls to the database just to add an employee.

Comment: it's very common in real world applications. there is a balance between performance and consistency.